# Найти все простые числа в интервале от 1 до N. Проблема в выводе. C++

Tags: c++

Не могу понять, где ошибка в коде, так как при вводе любого числа (например, 10) выдаются только 1, 2, 3, при том, что в этом диапазоне простыми являются еще и 5, 7. Помогите найти ошибку, пожалуйста.

```
using namespace std;                                                                        
int main() {
double N; 
cout << "Enter a number N: "; cin >> N;
bool isPrime = true;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    for (int j = 2; j * j <= i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isPrime) cout << i << " is prime number\n";
}
```

}

Comment: После того, как вы нашли перовое составное (кстати, 1 простым **не** является), вы флаг `isPrime` не меняете, и он для всех последующих чисел у вас `false`. Кстати, для диапазона от 1 до N быстрее будет применить решето Эратосфена. Да и в вашем коде — какой смысл проверять четные числа?..

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ!  И к слову о единице, преподаватель сказал, что в данном случае особого значения это не имеет, как и в ситуации с 0.

Comment: В данном алгоритме нельзя делать проверку `j * j <= i` (при больших `j` произойдет переполнение, и результат `j * j` для типа int будет отрицательным). Нужно вычислять корень квадратный из `i` и сравнивать `j` с ним)